# geom_sf fill fails when xlim, ylim are specified using coord_sf. Looking for a workaround when trying to create an animation using the av package

Tags: r, ggplot2, video, r-sf, gganimate

There is a known issue for `ggplot2` where the `geom_sf` function does not always work as excepted when specifying `xlim` and `ylim` using `coord_sf`. This issue seems to be specific to Windows, and the current work around involves saving the plot as a .png. [See GitHub link: geom_sf fill missing when xlim,ylim set in coord_sf](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3283)

The problem I am having is that I am not trying to make a static plot, but rather an animation that stitches hundreds of plots together using the `av` package.

Basically, I am looking for help implementing a suitable work around, and one that does not require saving or calling individual .png files.

Any ideas or suggestions would be great much appreciated.

The image below shows my motivation for solving this issue, mapping hurricane tracks across time. [image: Example of geom_sf fill not working in Windows when xlim and ylim are specified in coord_sf]

Stackoverflow does not allow for videos to be posted, so if you want to see the output my reproduceable code, you can look here at my original GitHub post which can be found here... [geom_sf, fill missing when xlim, ylim set in coord_sf in windows (follow-up to #3283) #4306](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4306)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(av)

tracts <- read_sf("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/230f9d23f6874be983901876cd600c4e_0.geojson") %>% 
  select(
    geometry,
    ALAND10,
    GEOID10
    )
st_crs(tracts)

set.seed(264)

v1 <- runif(1:dim(tracts)[1], .7, 1.25)

tracts2 <- cbind(tracts, v1)

tracts_2017 <- tracts2 %>%
  mutate(season=2017)

tracts_2018 <- tracts2 %>%
  mutate(
    season=2018,
    ALAND10 = ALAND10*v1
    )
tracts3 <- rbind(tracts_2017, tracts_2018) 
  st_crs(tracts3)

makeplot1 <- function(){
  datalist1 <- split(
    tracts3,
    tracts3$season
  )
  datalist2 <- split(
    tracts3,
    tracts3$season
  )
  mapply(function(data1, data2){
    p1 <- ggplot() + 
      geom_sf(
        data = data1,
        aes(fill = ALAND10)
      ) +
      geom_sf(
        data = data2 %>% st_union(),
        fill = alpha("red", 0.4),
        color = alpha("red", 0.4)
      ) +
      coord_sf(
        ylim = c( 43.04, 43.07),
        xlim = c(-76.14,-76.10),
        clip = "on",
        expand = F
      )
    print(p1)
    
    },
    datalist1, datalist2
  ) 
}

makeplot2 <- function(){
  datalist1 <- split(
    tracts3,
    tracts3$season
  )
  datalist2 <- split(
    tracts3,
    tracts3$season
  )
  mapply(function(data1, data2){
    p2 <- ggplot() + 
      geom_sf(
        data = data1,
        aes(fill = ALAND10)
      ) +
      geom_sf(
        data = data2 %>% st_union(),
        fill = alpha("red", 0.4),
        color = alpha("red", 0.4)
      ) 
    print(p2)
    
  },
  datalist1, datalist2
  ) 
}

video_file1 <- file.path(tempdir(), 'Tracts1.mp4')
av::av_capture_graphics(makeplot1(), video_file1, vfilter='framerate=fps=10')
av::av_media_info(video_file1)
utils::browseURL(video_file1)

video_file2 <- file.path(tempdir(), 'Tracts2.mp4')
av::av_capture_graphics(makeplot2(), video_file2, vfilter='framerate=fps=10')
av::av_media_info(video_file2)
utils::browseURL(video_file2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Thomas Lin Pedersen in the github issue you're linking, the solution would be to use the `png(..., type = 'cairo')` device on Windows machines. If you read the documentation at `?av::av_capture_graphics()`, you'll see that the `...` argument can be used to pass arguments to the `png()` function. Hence, I propose to do exactly that:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(av)

tracts <- read_sf("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/230f9d23f6874be983901876cd600c4e_0.geojson") %>% 
  select(
    geometry,
    ALAND10,
    GEOID10
  )
st_crs(tracts)

set.seed(264)

v1 <- runif(1:dim(tracts)[1], .7, 1.25)

tracts2 <- cbind(tracts, v1)

tracts_2017 <- tracts2 %>%
  mutate(season=2017)

tracts_2018 <- tracts2 %>%
  mutate(
    season=2018,
    ALAND10 = ALAND10*v1
  )
tracts3 <- rbind(tracts_2017, tracts_2018) 
st_crs(tracts3)

makeplot1 <- function(){
  datalist1 <- split(
    tracts3,
    tracts3$season
  )
  datalist2 <- split(
    tracts3,
    tracts3$season
  )
  mapply(function(data1, data2){
    p1 <- ggplot() + 
      geom_sf(
        data = data1,
        aes(fill = ALAND10)
      ) +
      geom_sf(
        data = data2 %>% st_union(),
        fill = alpha("red", 0.4),
        color = alpha("red", 0.4)
      ) +
      coord_sf(
        ylim = c( 43.04, 43.07),
        xlim = c(-76.14,-76.10),
        clip = "on",
        expand = F
      )
    print(p1)
    
  },
  datalist1, datalist2
  ) 
}

video_file1 <- file.path(tempdir(), 'Tracts1.mp4')
av::av_capture_graphics(makeplot1(), video_file1, 
                        vfilter='framerate=fps=10',
                        type = "cairo")
av::av_media_info(video_file1)
utils::browseURL(video_file1)
```

Furthermore,

> the current work around involves saving the plot as a .png.

is exactly what `av::av_capture_graphics()` is doing under the hood, and it is also what the `gganimate` package is doing.

Lastly, I'd recommend setting fixed limits on your colour scale as that seems to be changing between frames, complicating any interpretation. The `gganimate` package accounts for these details elegantly.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Also, I would like to use `gganimate`, but I have been having a lot of trouble getting it iterate over an sf.

Comment: just thought I would mention that I was able to work around the changing legend scale issue defining the scale's range. Something like `+scale_fill_viridis_c("Legend Title", limits = c(0, max_value_here)) `

Comment: Yes that seems the appropriate solution :)